# Use a #define VALUE with a template

Tags: c++

i cannot pass defined values to a template. Even a simple calculation doesnt work:

```
    #define IR_TIMEOUT 564*173/2
    return decodeSpace<IR_TIMEOUT>(
    duration);

    return decodeSpace<564*173/2>(
    duration);
```

Working:

```
    return decodeSpace<48786>(
    duration);
```

The definition:

```
    template <uint16_t irTimeout>
    bool decodeSpace(unsigned long duration){}
```

The error:

> E:\Arduino\sketchbook\libraries\IRLremote\IRLprotocolNEC.cpp: In member function 'virtual bool IRLprotocolNEC::decodeIR(long unsigned int)':
>   E:\Arduino\sketchbook\libraries\IRLremote\IRLprotocolNEC.cpp:46:11: error: no matching function for call to 'IRLprotocolNEC::decodeSpace(long unsigned int&)'
>      duration);
>              ^
>   E:\Arduino\sketchbook\libraries\IRLremote\IRLprotocolNEC.cpp:46:11: note: candidate is:
>   In file included from E:\Arduino\sketchbook\libraries\IRLremote/IRLprotocolNEC.h:27:0,
>                    from E:\Arduino\sketchbook\libraries\IRLremote\IRLprotocolNEC.cpp:24:
>   E:\Arduino\sketchbook\libraries\IRLremote/CIRLremote.h:103:9: note: template bool CIRLprotocol::decodeSpace(long unsigned int)
>       bool decodeSpace(unsigned long duration){
>            ^
>   E:\Arduino\sketchbook\libraries\IRLremote/CIRLremote.h:103:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
>   E:\Arduino\sketchbook\libraries\IRLremote\IRLprotocolNEC.cpp:46:11: error: overflow in constant expression [-fpermissive]
>      duration);
>              ^
>   E:\Arduino\sketchbook\libraries\IRLremote\IRLprotocolNEC.cpp:46:11: note: in template argument for type 'unsigned int'

Is this a bug or a feature? Or better: How can i avoid/solve things like this?

I want to create different different decoding functions with the same structure but different timings. Passing the values takes a lot of flash so i better copy the function over and over. Thatswhy i wanted to use templates.

Comment: template accept a type a in `<>`, not a variable

Comment: @Ever Those are non-type template parameters. Read up.

Comment: In what way does it fail?

Comment: Instead of "doesn't work", say what actually happens, and what you expected to happen. If it might be a compiler bug then include your compiler name and version

Comment: Can't reproduce on clang 3.4.1, g++ 4.9.0, or MSVC 2013. What's the compiler/version you are using?

Comment: [works in g++](http://ideone.com/l7yVSg)

Comment: Compiler text edited above. It seems it cant handle something like 564*60 but it can handle 564*10. No idea why. Even if both are under the ~65k uint16_t limit.

Comment: What compiler and version?

Comment: The error message seems to be saying that `uint16_t` is `unsigned int`, can you confirm that your platform has 16-bit ints?  (If that is true then writing `564 * 173` causes undefined behaviour due to signed int overflow)

Comment: and the fix would be to write `564ul * 173 / 2`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that 564*173 overflow uint16.

Use a define or a direct expression is the same thing when it comes for constant folding.

Constant folding is the fact that the compiler "expand" your expression. For example, replace "2*3" with "6".

Comment: Unsigned overflow is ok and well-defined.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `564*173` is signed overflow (if using 16-bit ints)

Comment: the weird thing is i can use 66000 which is an overflow but not 564*60 which shouldnt be an overflow. or are my calculations wrong??

Comment: @NicoHood `66000`'s type is probably `long` if `int` is 16 bits.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i needed to declare the calculation itself as long:

## define IR_TIMEOUT 564UL*173/2

Thx @  Matt McNabb

Comment: It was not the source of your current problem but please, if you really need to define constants as macros: put parenthesis around any expressions or you will get a lot more bad surprises of that kind.